# What does `total` mean in the field `mode` of `closeness` definition in `igraph` package?

Tags: r, igraph

What does `total` mean in the field `mode` of `closeness` definition in `igraph` package?

```
closeness(
  graph,
  vids = V(graph),
  mode = c("out", "in", "all", "total"),
  weights = NULL,
  normalized = FALSE
)
```

Comment: That seems to be incomplete in the documentation because `identical(closeness(g2, mode = "total"), closeness(g2, mode = "all"))
[1] TRUE` and in the documentation for `?degree` - `“all” is a synonym of “total”.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"total"` is an alias for `"all"`, i.e. for ignoring edge directions.